I'm trying to open activity B from activity A. It crashes as soon as I open and and I don't know why
I'm building a calorie counting app. From the home screen, I'm trying to open the "Create entry" activity, but it crashes the instant I open it. I can't tell why.
public class CreateEntryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Spinner spinnerFood;
    private EditText editTextGrams;
    private EditText editTextDate;
    private Button buttonSave;
    private Button buttonCreateFood;
    private List <Food> foods;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_entry);
        Food apple = new Food("Apple", 0.25, 0.5, 0.1, "None", 1);
        foods.add(apple);
        ArrayAdapter <Food> adapter = new ArrayAdapter < > (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, foods);
        spinnerFood.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinnerFood = findViewById(R.id.spinnerFoodEntry);
        editTextGrams = findViewById(R.id.editTextGramsEntry);
        editTextDate = findViewById(R.id.editTextDateEntry);
        buttonSave = findViewById(R.id.buttonSaveEntry);
        buttonCreateFood = findViewById(R.id.buttonCreateFood);

        buttonCreateFood.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(CreateEntryActivity.this, CreateFoodActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                Intent i = getIntent();
                Food food = (Food) i.getSerializableExtra("FOOD_KEY_");
                foods.add(food);
            }
        });
    }
}

If I remove all the code and only leave the xml, the activity opens.
Here is my logcat :
2024-06-24 12:19:09.975 26131-26131 AndroidRuntime          com.curs.licenta_lungutudor          D  Shutting down VM
2024-06-24 12:19:09.979 26131-26131 AndroidRuntime          com.curs.licenta_lungutudor          E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main (Ask Gemini)
Process: com.curs.licenta_lungutudor, PID: 26131
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.curs.licenta_lungutudor/com.curs.licenta_lungutudor.CreateEntryActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.List.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.List.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
    at com.curs.licenta_lungutudor.CreateEntryActivity.onCreate(CreateEntryActivity.java:52)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 


I'm pretty much a newbie, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, please?

We will need the stack of the crash to be able to help you

Can you please put log of your error

@Tudor have you checked my answer yet?

Does this answer your question? What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?

Tudor there are many issues with your code spinnerFood not initialised before setting the adapter. List foods is not initialised before adding elements to it. Also you are trying to get data from an Intent within the buttonCreateFood.setOnClickListener which is not the correct way to do.
You can try below code :
public class CreateEntryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Spinner spinnerFood;
    private EditText editTextGrams;
    private EditText editTextDate;
    private Button buttonSave;
    private Button buttonCreateFood;
    private List<Food> foods;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_entry);

        // Initialize UI components
        spinnerFood = findViewById(R.id.spinnerFoodEntry);
        editTextGrams = findViewById(R.id.editTextGramsEntry);
        editTextDate = findViewById(R.id.editTextDateEntry);
        buttonSave = findViewById(R.id.buttonSaveEntry);
        buttonCreateFood = findViewById(R.id.buttonCreateFood);

        // Initialize the foods list
        foods = new ArrayList<>();

        // Add a sample food item
        Food apple = new Food("Apple", 0.25, 0.5, 0.1, "None", 1);
        foods.add(apple);

        // Set the adapter for the spinner
        ArrayAdapter<Food> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, foods);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerFood.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Handle buttonCreateFood click
        buttonCreateFood.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(CreateEntryActivity.this, CreateFoodActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // Check if there is any data if yes then parse it
        Intent i = getIntent();
        if (i != null && i.hasExtra("FOOD_KEY_")) {
            Food food = (Food) i.getSerializableExtra("FOOD_KEY_");
            if (food != null) {
                foods.add(food);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Refresh the spinner to show new data
            }
        }
    }
}

If you still get any crash or doubt in any code part you can comment.

You need to initialise the variable before you use it
private List<Food> foods = new ArrayList<>()

Happy Coding...

According to the stackstrace, the foods list is null, so you can't do null.add, and indeed in your code I don't see when the foods list is initialized.

Your logs clearly state that there is some object which is not being initialized but  you are still trying to use it as a result it returns a null pointer exception. And that object is your "foods" list.
To fix this simply replace
private List<Food> foods;

with private List<Food> foods = new ArrayList<>()
now it will work fine.
